# Applied example of differential equations

Tags: analysis

In a homework, our professor gave us the following problem:

An ant walks along an elastic of length $l$ with a constant speed $v$. At the same time a man pulls on the extremity of the elastic with the same speed v.

How long will the ant walk for in order to get to the extremity of the elastic.

The problem is I don't know any of the properties of the elastic. How does it react to the man pulling on it? And what would be a good way find the solution to the problem?

Comment: You just need to assume that the elastic lengthens uniformly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume that at time $t$ the ant is at abscissa $x$. The elastic length is $l+vt$, so that the ant is dragged proportionally, at speed $v\dfrac{x}{l+vt}$. At the same time, it moves backwards at speed $v$.

Summing the two movements,

$$\frac{dx}{dt}=\frac{vx}{l+vt}-v,$$ with $x(0)=l$.

Using a symbolic solver,

$$x(t)=C(l+vt)-(l+vt)\log(l+vt).$$

The initial condition implies

$$l=Cl-l\log(l),$$ i.e.

$$C=1+\log(l).$$

Then the time is the solution of $x(T)=0$,

$$(1+\log(l))(l+vT)=(l+vT)\log(l+vT).$$

Comment: How do you fint x(t)?

Comment: @aribaldi: Using a symbolic solver.